# Update Control on User Control from Main Form

Tags: c#, user-controls, listbox

### Background

I have a main form that has a `tableLayoutPanel`. Within that I have three panel, a header, footer and left side bar. In the remaining space I add and remove `usercontrols` this one in the example is called `ctrlmanagepreset`.

Within these usercontrols I have controls. Namely a Listsbox s, that i'm trying to add items too.

I am getting the items from an xml file that does contain items and reading them in to an object list. The name of each object is then added to the listbox.

All of the Controls are accessable as I've made them public. I think it might be due to the way i create and add them?

### Question

Why aren't the Listboxes updating, showing the added items?

### Code

**Button click event that creates usercontrol**

```
 public void btnManage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new ctrlManagePresets () { Dock = DockStyle.Left }, 1, 1);
            PopulateCreateJob();

        }
```

**Method that Populates Listbox**

```
 public void PopulateCreateJob()
        {

            ctrlManagePresets ctrlmanagepresets = new ctrlManagePresets();

            //read in contents of xml file
            if (File.Exists(JoblistXmlFilepath))
            {

                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<Favourite>));
                TextReader reader = new StreamReader(JoblistXmlFilepath);

                //create list of old fave objects

                var xmlList = (List<Favourite>) deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

                reader.Close();

                if (xmlList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Favourite t in xmlList)
                    {
                        //add favourite objects to combobox
                        try
                        {
                            ctrlmanagepresets.lbCreateJob.Items.Add(t.Name);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(@"There is an object with no name in the XML.", @"Message",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                }
                ctrlmanagepresets.lbCreateJob.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
               ctrlmanagepresets.lbCreateJob.Items.Add(@"Settings File Not Found");
               ctrlmanagepresets.lbCreateJob.Enabled = false;
               ctrlmanagepresets.lbCreateJob.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the items to the instance of the control that you add to your tableLayoutPanel.

Just make your `PopulateCreateJob` return the instance that is built and intialized with the xml data

```
public void btnManage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrlManagePresets ctrl = PopulateCreateJob();
    ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Left; 
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(ctrl, 1, 1);
}


public ctrlManagePresets PopulateCreateJob()
{
    ctrlManagePresets ctrlmanagepresets = new ctrlManagePresets();
    // current code that initialize the instance of your control
    ....

    // return the control instance initialized to the caller
    return ctrlmanagepresets;
}
```